# Simplified polygons have overlapping lines

Tags: qgis

I am working with QGIS. I am creating a contour world map, I started my project with a raster image of the world and then extracted contour lines much too complex for my purposes. I simplified the polygons using a line generalization plugin. However I noticed that after simplifying some of my polygons are lapping into each other, how can I fix this. [image]

Comment: **do not try to generalize contours** it will only lead to this sort of mess. Resample your DEM to create more general contours. What method/tool are you using to generate your contours from your worldwide DEM?

Comment: I used raster-extract-contour to get my contour lines. Is there another method I can use that would output simpler polygons?

Comment: That sounds like the link to GDAL_Contour http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html which I have used and found to be quite reasonable, but tends to be a bit more on the engineering contour side (more blocky), have a read of an answer I posted http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/100251/qgis-contours-smoothing-and-cleaning/100303#100303 In your case I would resample the raster to a larger cell size using Bicubic or B-Spline method to filter out some of the worst lumps before generating your contours.

Comment: So how should I go about doing this? Is there a plugin I can download or what? Sorry I am quite new to this.

Comment: There is a tool in the toolbox https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/grid_tools/resampling.html or you can use Translate (GDAL_Translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) with a changed cell size, but be sure to use GDAL 2.0+ to specify -r bilinear

Comment: The thing is I have no experience with coding, I was hoping for a simple plugin or menu-bar tool that could do this for me. Im just a kid, I know nothing of c++ or GDAL.

Comment: There's no coding in those links. The first is from the toolbox http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html and the second, GDAL_Translate, is accessible from the QGIS menus (Raster::Translate) but there's not a help page for that (that I know of), the options are explained in the command line (CMD) tool and are the same for the GUI.

Comment: Thanks! I used the translate method and It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using GRASS.  According to this post:  [Generalizing polygon file while maintaining topology in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20799/generalizing-polygon-file-while-maintaining-topology-in-qgis), GRASS will handle topology.  So, before you generalize, set up topology and then use GRASS v.generalize to simplify the polygons.

However, as Michael Miles-Stimson pointed out, you are better off resampling your DEM at a lower resolution to create the generalize contours.  This will be much more accurate that generalizing contours you have already produced.